# make file missing, Eclipse

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, build, makefile

First I should say that I've looked around for a solution to this problem and found many related answers but nothing that's quite solved things for me.

My problem is that whenever I try to build a solution in Eclipse (Juno), I get a the following error message:

02:32:36 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project Project 1 ****

make all

Cannot run program "make": Launching failed

Error: Program "make" not found in PATH
PATH=[C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\MinGW\bin]

02:32:36 Build Finished (took 133ms)

If you look at the final entry in the make path, you can see that its C:\MinGW\bin. I've looked in bin, and the make file *is* there. I've run it using cmd to make sure its working, and it is.

One solution I tried is renaming the make program (by default its called mingw32-make.exe) to make.exe. That seem like a step in the right direction, as it change the error to the following:

02:26:23 **** Build of configuration Default for project Project 1 ****

make all

make: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop.

02:26:24 Build Finished (took 82ms)

I looked around to try and find how to change the build settings, and found solutions for C/C++ that allow me to avoid 'all', but they don't help as I'm trying to compile a Java program.

The program I'm trying to build is below.

```
public class Hello {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double hi = 5+2.4;
        System.out.println(hi);
    }

}
```

The most baffling part of all this is that I've been happily using Eclipse for months before this error just pop up  out of the blue today. I'm really at my wits end, if you guys could help me out I would really appreciate it!

Thanks alot

Comment: Insufficient data -- are you running this from eclipse?  Also, it isn't looking for the makefile, it's looking for the make program.  A path to THAT has to be on the path somewhere.

Comment: @rcook Yes I am running it from eclipse, and to be more specific I should have said make.exe. I'll edit the post, but in the meantime the make program is in the path.

Comment: Right click on the project, go to properties and select "Builders" in the menu on the left in the properties window. For a normal java program this should say "Java Builder", is this messed up somehow? (e.g. does it say "Program"?)

Comment: Using `make` to build java is a bit unusual I think, usually `ant` or `maven` or something like that is used. So you may have somehow messed up project type or build steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much for the suggestions, however unfortunately they didn't solve my problem.

I was able to solve the problem once I realized that the error was of C/C++ type (the error type is viewable when you click on the problems tab in the console window). I don't use eclipse with C/C++ anymore, so what I did was just remove all C/C++ functionality from my version of Eclipse. That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check:

you might have some executable called "make" on the path before the one you intend to use.  Try doing this from the command line, or use a "whereis" program if available.

You also might have things in eclipse that are not synched with the file system.  In case you are unaware, eclipse keeps its own copy of its files, and you must synchronize with the computer's file system if you use tools that use their own processes outside of eclipse.  To sync your project, select the project in project explorer and click f5 (there are menu options as well, I just don't remember them).

Let us know...